# How can I find the value of this variable in firefox debugger?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, firefox, angularjs-scope

I am new to debugging JavaScript and AngularJS.  I have breakpoints in virtually every line of the following code segment, but I am not able to find the `response` variable or `data` or `content` in the Firefox debugger.  There is a very dense nested structure of variables in the debugger.  **Where do I look in the Firefox debugger variables structure to find the values for `response` or `data` or `content` in the code below?**

The alert says that the `confirmStatus` variable's value has not changed from its default and thus was not populated by the call to the backend service, even though the backend service call produced console logs indicating that it was fired.  I want to find out what is coming back and in what form so that I can alter the client side code below.

Here is the segment of Javascript code that I am running through the debugger:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    var str1 = "/confirm-email?d=";
    var str2 = $routeParams.d;
    var res = str1.concat(str2);
    $http.post(res).then(function(response) {
        $scope.confirmStatus = response.data.content;
            });
    var str3 = "confirmStatus is: ";
    alert(str3.concat($scope.confirmStatus))

    alert("viewContentLoaded!")
});
```

Comment: ajax is asynchronous. You can't look for the response until it has been returned which is why it is wrapped in the `then` promise callback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using the debugger first. This means:

- open the debugger with the developer tools menu or keyboard shortcut: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Open_the_debugger
- Pick the file you want to debug, key shortcut is  on mac, then type in part of your .js file to have it open in the debugger.
- You should see the source code for your .js file now, and you can click in the left-nav to the line you want to stop on, e.g. the $scope.confirmStatus = ....

There is also a good trick with angular where you can access the scope from the console. To do this

- Again open the developer tools this time to the console not debugger
- Right-click on the page near some html owned by angular, and pick "Inspect element"
- In the console: angular.element($0).scope(), and you will have access to the controller scope for that element.

That said, you might want to try and capture the error handler for the http.post. e.g.

```
$http.post(res).then(function(response) {}, 
                     function(err) {});
```

Comment: Thank you and +1.  The confusion was that I had too many breakpoints.  When I reduced it to just one breakpoint at `$scope.confirmStatus = response.data.content;`, the response object became visible in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that this function will run in parallel to current one, at a later stage when response will come from server:

```
function(response) {
    $scope.confirmStatus = response.data.content;
}
```

You should put a debugger break point into this $http callback function -- response variable will be destroyed as soon as callback function execution will end.

Your alert will always display unmodified confirmStatus, because confirmStatus is changed in callback function which will be executed later when response will come from server.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for a correct and early amswer. Though your answer is correct, I somehow umderstood the wording of the other answer first yesterday.

Comment: I would like to note that “in parallel” is incorrect. The JavaScript threading model is to not have threads, ever. It *will* run asynchronously as a callback, but no other user code will be running concurrently with the callback, so no parallelism is happening in the JavaScript itself.